# How to add a custom highlighting rule in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

How does one add a custom highlighting rule in PyCharm? I mean, for example:

```
html = """
    <html>
        <body>
            In %s hour(s) it will be %s.
        </body>
    </html>
    """ % (offset, dt)
```

Pycharm does not highlight the `%s` part of the string, which the variable `html` holds. How does one add a rule such that the `%` in a string and the letter after it will be highlighted or shown in a different color? This feature is available in Sublime Text 2, so I hope it can be made possible with PyCharm 2.7.1 as well.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it does it, but it'd make a pretty nice feature request.

Comment: You can't tweak PyCharm this way, it uses strict language parsers and it needs to know what language or template system is used, Alt+Enter, inject language, specify what exactly is inside this text variable. As it's not pure a HTML, highlighting of variables will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much research, I've realised that this cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a custom rule to an existing language - but you can add a custom file type/language: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/creating-and-registering-file-types.html

(This answer does not address this question specifically, but Google sent me here when trying to figure out how to add my own highlighting, so adding this to help others)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what the OP is after, but there's a handy PyCharm/IntelliJ plugin for adding colour to comments which is what I was after

The plugin is called **Comments Highlighter** and the page for this plugin is:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12895-comments-highlighter

Here's a sample from the plugin page:

[image: sample-comment-colouring]

Comment: This has recently been renamed to *Better Highlights*, available at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12895-better-highlights